# Python 3 unit-testing, create mock of singleton class function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I'm working on creating unittests for my project.

I have a class called TimerHandler that needs to be tested. This class uses a class called AudioHandler. Both of these classes are singletons. see code below.

timer_handler.py

```
class TimerHandler(metaclass=Singleton):

    def play(self):
        # some code that needs to be tested

        AudioHandler().start()
```

audio_handler.py

```
class AudioHandler(metaclass=Singleton):

    def start(self):
        # some code that connects with an audio device
```

I'm trying to mock the start method of AudioHandler so it will just return None and won't try to connect to an audio device. The unittest looks like this:

```
@patch.object(AudioHandler, 'start', return_value=None)
def test_play_pause(self, start):

    self.timer_handler.play()
```

The problem is that it is still running the code in the original start function in AudioHandler.

How can I write a test function that removes/mocks the functionality of the start function in AudioHandler?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should mock a class from a module path where you are importing it

```
@patch('timer_handler.AudioHandler')
```

And after that, you can add your method to the mock object

Please read
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch